# Exiting Stata without saving changes in data

Tags: stata

I use the code below to load a dataset into memory:

```
use D:\d\all_vars_ready.dta , clear
```

Is there a way to prevent Stata from asking "save changes in data" before exiting?

Ideally, I would like to do this from within a `do` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me *interactively*:

```
exit, clear
```

This command will close Stata without asking to save any changes in the dataset.

From within a `do` file, you also need to specify the `STATA` option:

```
exit, clear STATA
```